# How to use multiple options for dropdown select value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu

`<%= f.collection_select :sportist_id, Sportist.order("CREATED_AT DESC"),:id,:name, include_blank: true %>`

I'd like to be able to select a sportist by name AND surname, but as far as I can figure out, only one option for the dropdown value can persist. Is it possible to somehow combine `:name + :surname` so that they work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a full_name attribute in your model class:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}".strip
end
```

and use it in your select:

```
<%= f.collection_select :sportist_id, Sportist.order("CREATED_AT DESC"),:id,:full_name, include_blank: true %>
```